# PhpStorm - Export files changed between two commits under Git

Tags: git, phpstorm

Is the opportunity in **PhpStorm** to export changed files between two commits under **Git**? Now I'm using **Git console** command and ***tarring*** changed files into archive at once.

```
tar -czvf %FILE_NAME%.tar $(git diff --diff-filter=[ACMRT] --name-only %COMMIT_HASH_0% %COMMIT_HASH_1%)
```

P.S. I'm using PhpStorm 6.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in PhpStorm; the closest thing that is there is the possibility to save each commit as a patch (Changes toolwindow, Log tab, right-click a commit, select "Create Patch...")

The Git command line is so flexible that there is no way for any tool vendor to provide a GUI for all the operations that are possible through the command line.

Comment: Yeah, I used to see that possibility (creating pathes). Ok, thanks. I thought there is some option like in TortoiseGit.